# If a function is integrable over the whole space, then is it zero except on a set of finite measure?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the converse true?  If so, can I use this to show that if $f$ and $g$ are integrable then $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ is integrable with respect to the product measure?

Comment: The converse to your statement is of course not true.  The converse says "If a function is 0 except on a set of finite measure, then it is integrable over the whole space."   Think of an easy example why this is not true.

Comment: Yeah I can use harmonic series to show 1/x can't be finite around 0.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in your title is no; for example, let $X=(1,\infty)$, and let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$. Then
$$\int_X f\,dm=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx=\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_{x=1}^{x=\infty}=(-0)-(-1)=1,$$
even though $f$ is non-zero everywhere on $X$, and $X$ has infinite measure.

The converse is also false; for example, let $X=(0,1)$, and let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Then
$$\int_X f\,dm=\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\left[\ln(x)\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}=(-0)-(-\infty)=\infty,$$
even though $X$ has finite measure and therefore $f$ is zero except on a set of finite measure.